# why won't background-image:url work with a local jpeg? but it does with a remote pexels jpeg...?

Tags: html, styles, background-image

I can't get the following html (background-image:url and or src won't work for me either) to work and I am struggling. Can someone please look at it for me?

this code does not work...

```
<body style=background-image:url(final-assets\img\mscutts-main-splash-blue.jpg)>
```

this does....

```html
<body style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/52599/pexels-photo-52599.jpeg)">
```

[image: Sample of code]

Comment: `final-assets\img\mscutts-main-splash-blue.jpg` is a very unlikely looking (relative) URL.

Comment: Thank you. I kept screwing around with it and finally added a link in css.

Comment: Background image and aligning and justifying items drive me crazy. I only just beginning so thank you for your guys's help.

Answer (score 1):

try this, use '/' instead of '\'

```html
<body style="background-image:url(final-assets/img/mscutts-main-splash-blue.jpg)">
```

Answer (score -1):

the only problem with your code is the slashes, change all the backward slashes() to the forward shasles(/), please do the same

```
<body
 style="background-image:url(final-assets/img/mscutts-main-splash-blue.jpg)">
```